# What do these gear stats mean/do?

Tags: everquest

I just started playing EQ since it's free now. I'm a lvl 7 noob, and I'm confused about some of the gear stats. Are there any good websites out there that explains what lots of the in-game stuff does?

More specifically, can somebody explain what these mean/do: `Rec Lvl`, `AC` (accuracy?), `End` (phys. defense?), `Purity`, `Magic` (and are the stats underneath it for offense or defense?), `Clairvoyance`, `Modified/Unmodified`, and `Slot/Type`. If you don't want to take the time to explain all those, please at least tell me what `Rec Lvl` and `AC` do. Thanks for your time.

Here is picture of some boots showing these stats

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have personally played EQ but looking at the wiki, i found this page.

[Item Stat Explination](http://everquest.allakhazam.com/wiki/EQ:Lucy_Item_Definitions)

So to answer your questions:

Rec LvL: Recommended Level. This means to what level your toon can wear the item before it becomes obsolete.

AC = Armor Class or Count. This is your armor level. Like other games, the higher your armor level, the more physical damage reduction you have.

End = Endurance. Reading it from the list, this seems to be your energy regeneration for classes that do not use mana. This is usually for rogue style classes.

Purity = This seems to be a stat regarding modification. From the link i provided, it talks about how the level of purity is tied to the level of enchantment you can use on it.

Magic = Unsure but for most RPG games i've played, this is typically your Magic Resistance. It should work that the higher your magic level, the more resistance to damage from that family of magic.

Clairvoyance = This according to the link refers to the efficiency of your spell casting. In other words, the higher the clairvoyance, the more mana you gain back.

Modified/Unmodified = Applies to whether the item has been modified through enchantments or other items.

Slot/Type = not really sure...

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but for anyone else stumbling into it, the best answer is don't worry about the huge lists of stats as a new player.  This is a lvl 7 guy looking at lvl 80 gear.  Just play the game naturally and you'll learn the important terms from people as you go along.  The basics you really need to keep in mind are:

AC: Higher the better, lessens incoming damage

HP: How many bonus HP the item gives you.

Delay (on weapons): How fast a weapon is.  You want this to be a low number.

Attack (weapons): How much base damage it does.  Further modified by your skills.

REC: Recommended level of item.  Some don't fully function until you meet this requirement. Stats will be reduced.

REQ: Required level of item. In this case you can't ust it al all until you reach that level.

Now stop reading and go beat things up!